# Google Tag Manager - Capture Multiple URLs as one URL

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager (GTM) and the web application has multiple URL's for the same page due to the frameworks.

For example the following four (4) URLS load the same page:
    /
    /#/
    /public/home
    /public/home#/

Another example: 
    /resources
    /resources#/

How do I tell GTM that a group of URL's are actually the SAME page?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about a few urls you could use a lookup table - choose your url path as the input variable, enter your paths on the left side and use the right side of the assignment to set a unified path as output.

If you have many urls it might be better to solve that on the framework level and have it output a key/value pair to the dataLayer, i.e.

```
dataLayer.push({
'virtualPath' = '/remains-the-same-for-all-variations/'
})
```

and use that instead of the url field within GTM.